# How to use Kotlin extension property of function type with Android data binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, extension-methods, android-databinding

I defined a Kotlin extension property of function type:

```
@set:BindingAdapter("myListener")
var View.myListener: ((Boolean) -> Unit)?
    get() {
        // ...
    }
    set(value) {
        // ...
    }
```

I'm now trying to use that in an Android data binding call. First I defined a method against my `ViewModel` (which is a variable `viewModel` within my databinding).

```
@MainThread
fun notify(value: Boolean) {
    if (value) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Then tried to use that method in my binding layout XML:

```
<TextView
    ...
    app:myListener="@{viewModel::notify}"
    />
```

But it gives a compiler error "Listener class 'kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<? super java.lang.Boolean,kotlin.Unit>' with method 'invoke' did not match signature of any method 'app:myListener'".

I also tried this way, with calling the method in an expression:

```
<TextView
    ...
    app:myListener="@{(b) -> viewModel.notify(b)}"
    />
```

But it also gave an error, this time on startup: "cannot find method notify(java.lang.Object) in class com.example.ui.models.MyViewModel".

I've managed to use data binding before with Kotlin extension functions returning types other than function, and I've also used data binding with method reference to listeners that are defined via an interface. But I'm not sure how to combine the two.